# my links are not showing correctly no equal sign php

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

Am sending through a mail with a link does not show the equal sign or a complete link when I open my mail in gmail or in hotmail or any other mail software

```
$reg = new REGISTRATION();
$reg->email = rtrim($_POST["email"]);
$reg_email =  $reg->email;
$id =rtrim(md5($reg_email.time()));
$link="http://".$url."activate.php?token=$id&code=$code";


$to = $reg->email;
$subject = "Activate Profile";
$message = "Thank you for registering with us please click the link below to activate your account.\n\n".$link."\n\nLogin details\n\nUsername:$reg_email\nPassword:$reg_pass";
$headers = "From: "."registration@domain.com". PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;



mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you define `$code` in `$link` ?

```
$reg = new REGISTRATION();
$reg->email = rtrim($_POST["email"]);
$reg_email =  $reg->email;
$id =rtrim(md5($reg_email.time()));
$code = YOUR_CODE_HERE;
$link="http://".$url."activate.php?token=".$id."&code=".$code;
```

Comment: link is already defined when I echo the $link it shows the complete correct url. Only in the mailboxes when things don't appear

Comment: Can you give an example of a link you create?

Comment: and what you got in mail?

Comment: What if you use `htmlspecialchars`? Try this: `$link="http://".$url."activate.php?token=$id&code=".htmlspecialchars($code);`

Comment: Change your `Content-type` to `Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`